# How to have lombok plugin in intellij 2021

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-lombok-plugin

Well i would like to have lombok for my project that im trying to build , however the Intellij IDEA 2021.3.4 doesn't include it or i dont know how to include it .

Is there a workaround to include lombok into the Intellij IDEA. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lombok plug-in is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA:

[image: lombok]